# How does jQuery "empty:"-selector works? (remove empty tags)

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors, is-empty

I'm trying to remove all the empty tags from DOM-tree. Empty means both completely empty (like `<a></a>`) and with several whitespaces (like `<a>  ...</a>`). Also inner empty tags should also be removed. E.g.

```
<p style="text-align:right;">     <a> </a>  <a></a></p><p>Hello</p>
```

should leave

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

Because after deleting empty `<a> </a>  <a></a>` an empty `<p style="text-align:right;">  </p>` would still remain and should be removed.

**What I'm doing:**

```
$.(".container>*:empty").remove();
```

And the result was confusing. I've started to debug with such code:

```
console.log($.(".container>*:empty").size());
```

1) String:

```
Well, though it looks like a paragraph, it's not o_O.
0 (I'm wrapping string in global wrapper .container)
```

2) String

```
<a></a><a>Well, though it looks like a paragraph, it's not o_O.</a>
1
```

3) String

```
<a> </a><a>Well, though it looks like a paragraph, it's not o_O.</a>
0 (It seems one whitespace makes a non-empty)
```

4) String

```
<p> <a></a></p>  <a>Well, though it looks like a paragraph, it's not o_O.</a>
0 (<a></a> is not selected as empty (maybe 'cause it's inside of < p>). 
   Also p is not selected, besides it contains only empty < a>)
```

**My questions are:**

- how to make `:empty` select both empty tags and with 1-N whitespaces?
- how to make `:empty` select all the empty tags inside every objects?

My idea is to do `${"*:empty"}.remove() while $('*:empty').size() > 0`.

**UPDATE:**

```
do {
$(".container *").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === ""
}).remove();
} while ($(".container *").filter(function() {
return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === ""
}).size() > 0)
console.log($(".container").html())
```

Apply this code to:

```
<p> <p> <a> <a>  <a><br><hr></a> </p>  <a>Well, though it looks like a paragraph, it's not o_O.</a></p>
```

And we get:

```
<p>   <a>Well, though it looks like a paragraph, it's not o_O.</a></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pZub2/)

```
$(".container *")
    .filter(function(){
         return $(this).is(':not(br)') 
                && $(this).is(':not(img)') 
                && $.trim(this.innerHTML) === ""
     }).remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, such string "<p> <p> <a> <a>  <a></br></br></a> </p>  <a>Well, though it looks like a paragraph, it's not o_O.</a></p>" returns "<p>    <a>Well, though it looks like a paragraph, it's not o_O.</a></p>" after your code. It seems </br> is also considered as empty. I bet, img, hr and all other single tags would be the same. How to aviod this?

Comment: </br> is not a tag, i think you mean <br> sometimes wrote <br/>

Comment: I have tested it, <br> and <hr> are keeped, but not img. I will update answer to give you idea on how to apply specific filter

Comment: I've also tested and updated my post. BR are removed. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are correct, retested it and <br> are removed, so just exclude them with filter, see update